# How to get ratio of 2 field data

Tags: mysql

I want to get the ratio of 2 field data from mysql

Example i have this data:

```
width  height
1024  | 960
2880  | 1800
1440  | 900
```

I want to get the ratio of these data(example 4:3, 16:9, etc.)
so the output should be:

```
width  height
4  | 3
8  | 5
8  | 5
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can check whether the ratio's match with a switch case/if statement. E.g. 1440/900=1.6=(16/10)

Comment: do you know all the possible ratios beforehand?

Comment: @Jayvee not at all, may different each data. btw my data are list of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is then to reduce a fraction (witdth/height) to its simplest form, in which case we can call a function to give us the Greatest Common Factor between those two numbers to divide into:

```
select width, height, width/gcd(width,height) wratio, 
height/gcd(width,height) hratio
from wh
```

Function gcd:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gcd(x int, y int) RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE dividend int;
  DECLARE divisor int;
  DECLARE remainder int;
  SET dividend := GREATEST(x, y);
  SET remainder := LEAST(x, y);

  WHILE remainder != 0 DO
    SET divisor = remainder;
    SET remainder = MOD(dividend, divisor);
    SET dividend = divisor;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN divisor;
END
```

Note: I found the gcd function here: http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=143

tested in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92b92/2)

Comment: You're calling your function twice per row, do you consider a way of calling it only once? Upvoted, by the way :)

Comment: thanks leonardo, it's a good point, probably is more efficient to select width, height, gcd(width, height) in a subquery and then do the divisions in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
SELECT * , (
width / IF(height=0,1,height)
) AS ratio
FROM  `my_table`
```

But be careful: do not `divide by 0`

Comment: That is decimal/percentage ratio, i need integer not decimal